# embedding svg figures in rmarkdown child files

Tags: r, svg, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I have a Rmd report that looks like this:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

Some text

```{r child="children/stuff.Rmd", results="asis", cache=FALSE}
```
````

The stuff.Rmd file is in a subfolder of the project called *children*. The image I want to include is in a subfolder of the project called *figures*.

stuff.Rmd looks like this, and the **image preview in RStudio works**:

```
something, something
![this is a picture](figures/school_stages.svg)
```

It seems to be erroring out on the child rmd not being able to find the _school_stages.svg_, you can see this error when editing the child

```
(no image at path figures/school_stages.svg)
```

knitting the file gives an error, apparently from the child Rmd:

```
! Unable to load picture or PDF file 'figures/school_stages.svg'.
```

Changing figure.Rmd to:

```
something, something
![this is a picture](../figures/school_stages.svg)
```

gets rid of the error in edit mode but on knitting gives:

```
! Unable to load picture or PDF file '../figures/school_stages.svg'.
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

RStudio Version 1.2.1335
Knitr version 1.23

Comment: works fine for me on macOS. What OS do you use?

Comment: Windows. With the latest version of rstudio

Comment: And was it an svg? I'll test this with a png as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is highly dependent on the image type. `.png` and `.pdf` are fine, but `.svg` (plain or inkscape versions don't currently work)